# Converting a thresholded image into a byte array?

Tags: c#, image, byte, aforge, threshold

Can someone please tell me about how to convert a thresholded image stored in a 'Bitmap' variable into a byte array and view the byte array in a text box or a text file, in C#?

Can someone please help me with the code to it?

i have threshoded the image using Aforge.net - [link](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/b2bd54da-46c2-cb64-3577-0962d8f56554.htm). And trying to view the byte array of it in 1s and 0s.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is Bitmap you can use

*LockBits* and then *Scan0* methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

```
  public static Byte[] BmpToArray(Bitmap value) {
      BitmapData data = value.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, value.Width, value.Height),   ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, value.PixelFormat);

      try {
        IntPtr ptr = data.Scan0;
        int bytes = Math.Abs(data.Stride) * value.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        return rgbValues;
      }
      finally {
        value.UnlockBits(data);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain it with a code snippet of how to exactly do it?

Thank you

Comment: Sir, you code snippet works perfectly and gave the output as i excpected from 0s and 255s representing the thresholded image in black and white.

as soon as i got 15 reputations, i'll rate up your answer

Comment: Excellent, though you should consider outputting the stride as out parameter, since it is necessary for manipulating the data. Though I guess it's possible to just divide the array length by the image height...